# Can't select a device from flutter device selection

Tags: android, flutter, sdk, android-emulator, ide

On android studio I can't debug real or emulated devices on a flutter project. I only see options to select Chrome (web), Edge (web) or Windows (desktop) as options on the flutter device selection dropdown window.

I can see the devices under the Device Manager menu such as when I connect my android device using a usb cable but somehow they don't appear under flutter device selection. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling everything multiple times, I tried installing the Android SDK and Android studio in different places, I even connected different android devices to see if the problem was due to my device but none were seen by the flutter device selection even after a refresh.

All the tested devices had USB debugging open so I have no idea what may be causing this. Emulated devices such as an emulated pixel 3 were similarly visible in the device manager but could not be selected for debugging. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: How many devices are there when you run `flutter devices` or `flutter doctor`?

Comment: What does `adb devices` print?

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem, It was a multitude of issues that compounded on top of eachother.

1. I had not properly set the path for flutter, even flutter doctor wasn't working. When I properly installed flutter, flutter doctor gave me the an error to do with command line tools.
2. I could not resolve the command line tools issue on flutter doctor even after I had downloaded the latest command line tools from the sdk manager. I found out that the issue was due to me not installing the Android SDK in the default installation location. When I installed it in the default install location I just had to agree to the license agreements and after that it all worked properly.